# Uploading Dynamic Number of Files with PDO

Tags: php, pdo

**EDIT** [*Here is a similar thread*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43839980/upload-multiple-files-pdo?rq=1)

I'm trying to upload potentially multiple files from a dynamic HTML form.

A `<button>` is able to add image inputs to a form, like so:

```
<button onclick="addImage()">Add Image</button>
```

Accompanying `<script>` function that adds the image `<input>`:

```
function addImage() {
    $("form").append('<div><input type="file" name="image[]" id="uploadImage" multiple><button class="remove">Remove</button></div>');
}
```

When I click the Upload button for the form, no errors are thrown, but the files do not end up in either the database or the image folder.

Below is the PHP PDO attempt at making this work:

```
//SQL Statement
$statementImage = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table (date, title, image) value (:date, :title, :image)");

//if an image is prepared for upload
if(isset($_FILES['image']['name'])) {

    //if no image was attached to upload input
    foreach($_FILES['image']['error'] as $err){
        switch ($err){
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
            echo 'No file sent.';
            exit;
            }
        }

    //check for correct extension
    for($x=0; $x<count($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']); $x++){

        $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'][$x];
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$x];

        $t = explode(".", $file_name);
        $t1 = end($t);
        $file_ext = strtolower(end($t));

        $ext_check = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "svg");

        //move file to folder
        if(in_array($file_ext, $ext_check)){
            $filer = $file_tmp;
            $filepath = "images/" . $file_name;
            move_uploaded_file($filer, $filepath);

            //SQL statement
            $statementImage->execute(['date' => $date, 'title' => $title, 'image' => $file_name]);
            } else{
                echo "Only images can be stored.";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**I'm sort of wondering whether `if(isset($_FILES['image']['name'])) {` is the correct way to ask whether files have been appended to an input or not.**

Comment: you can not check `if(isset($_FILES['image']['name']))` like this because `image[]` field name is an array. You need to check by traversing the `image[]` field

Comment: I figured this was a problem..what is the proper syntax for something like this?

Comment: Does this need to be wrapped within a `foreach` statement to go through each possible image?

Comment: do you only want to check only condition right?

Comment: Yes, I only want to check if files were added to file input